# What is a phrase or analogy for something that has both fixed and customizable parts?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, analogy

I am looking for a way to describe to my students that some of their courses must be taken at a certain time while others can be taken whenever. Therefore, I am trying to give an example or phrase about something that has both fixed parts and parts that are movable or customizable in some  way.

Comment: A 'snowclone' fits, but hardly clarifies. I'd stick to a simple literal explanation: partly strictly timetabled, partly to be done by a fixed deadline but at your own convenience.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting observation...recently I have seen newer vocab that includes 'snow' as a political statement. Gonna look that up...

Comment: Just tell them. An analogy will only confuse the situation.

Comment: I'd go with food.  You could come up with something involving a Chinese restaurant.  Also, pizzas have crust, tomato sauce and cheese in common (slight oversimplification there), but then you can choose your own toppings.  Or are you saying that all of the courses are required, but the flexibility lies in the order some of the courses are taken in?  In that case, again, food.  The meal will always begin with soup and end with dessert, but in between you could vary the order, e.g. salad then meat, or meat then salad, or salad and meat at the same time.  Something like that.

Comment: If all the courses are required, you could still work with pizza, but the different cooks put the toppings on in a different order.

Comment: Once you get on this 20-hour trans-Atlantic flight, you will get your Meals at fixed times, but you can ask for Water & Drinks when-ever you want. Meals == Exams ; Water & Drinks == Assignments & Exercises